# C# Dynamic label across rows and column of a winform

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I am working on a hotel software and i want to display all the room on a WinForm with label on run-time. the room status will be pulled from the database, the color of the label will change according to the room status. please how to i go about creating this.

Below is an Example of the form layout that I want to achieve.

[image: Example of the form layout]

Edited:

```
private void Charts(GroupBox group, Label label, string roomNo)
    {
        var room = RoomServices.CheckRoom(roomNo);

        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(room.Id));

        try
        {
            if (room.RoomStatusId == 4)
            {
                group.BackColor = Color.Red;
                group.ForeColor = Color.White;
                group.Text = roomNo;
                var c = RoomServices.FindCheckIn(room.Id);

                string name = c.Guest.FirstName + " " + c.Guest.Surname;
                label.Text = name;

            }
            else if (room.RoomStatusId == 3)
            {
                group.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                group.ForeColor = Color.White;
                group.Text = roomNo;
                label.Text = "OUT of Order";

            }
            else if (room.RoomStatusId == 2)
            {
                group.BackColor = Color.Brown;
                group.ForeColor = Color.White;
                group.Text = roomNo;
                label.Text = "Room Dirty";
            }
            else if (room.RoomStatusId == 5)
            {
                group.BackColor = Color.Coral;
                group.ForeColor = Color.White;
                group.Text = roomNo;
                label.Text = "Room Reserved";
            }
            else
            {
                group.BackColor = Color.Green;
                group.ForeColor = Color.White;
                group.Text = roomNo;
                label.Text = "Room Arrival";
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: No just asking how to go about that. this a guide

Comment: I'll give you a guide: 1- Create the labels and add them to your form 2.-change the color depending on the room status

Comment: New to c# just learning it. am really confused  about it.

Comment: @Pikoh that i have already the issues is the what rooms numbers changes i wanted it dynamic

Comment: @rilly009 then edit your question and add what you have now and where exactly is your problem, as your question is about to be closed

Comment: Sorry but this question is not a good fit for SO. You really should read [ask] because you are requesting a general tutorial on your specific problem. Instead you should try to write some code and then ask questions about it (explaining the broad scenario you are trying to resolve). I can only suggest to look at how TableLayoutPanel (or FlowLayoutPanel) works and fill it with buttons

Comment: @Steve Thanks for the FlowLayoutPanel suggestion that all what i wanted .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used UserControl and FlowLayoutPanel to resolve this